# Getting a value before it is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, textfield, onchange

I am having trouble with getting a value in a text box before the value is changed either by user input or programmatically.

I figure it has to do with the `_TextChanged` event but once this executes how do I get the old value which was already there before the change?

For example number `3` is in the text field. The number then changes to `4` how do I save `3`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not store anything in the `TextBox`.  Use it only to display/edit `value`.

```
private string value;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // at this moment value is still old
    var oldValue = value;
    value = ((TextBox)sender).Text; // text1.Text

    // here you have oldValue and new value
}
```

Maybe you don't want to update `value` after each `TextChanged`. Maybe you will do it when form is closed, some button is pressed, etc.

Anyhow idea should be clear: if you need to have old value, then store it somewhere yourself (as a variable, as a `Tag`, as application setting, exporting, etc.).

Also, take care about how user will work. If `TextBox` contains `3`, then user may first press `4` and only then delete `3`. Or user may accidentally press `54`. Which of those will be *old* value: `3`, `34`, `54` ? Simply to demonstrate you, what there could be consequent problems to having concept of *old value*. Mayhaps you don't want it and there is better solution to what you are trying to solve by getting old value.

Comment: Best answer so far.. reason I need it is because I am trying to move a button from one location to another and swap them if the button already exists. So to do this I need to know the old position as well as the new position. Having great difficulty with this and may post another question. But as far as this is concerned to answered the question near enough.. although what I ended up doing was using the `_Enter` event to save the old value ;)

Comment: Good idea to save old value when control gets focus. If you like, other idea could be to use both `_Leave` and `_KeyDown` (with `Enter` key pressed) to *confirm* user input. Otherwise, if user entering `100`, then by using `_TextChanged` you will do 3 operations at positions: `1`, `10` and finally at `100`. I think property window of designer is using that concept (to confirm input by `Enter` or on focus lost).

Comment: If you look at my next question (lot harder) you will see why this value is needed..

Answer (score 2):

Why not save the current value in the textbox in a variable during the textchanged event. That way, it is the "previous" value when the event is fired again.

Comment: You are saving the current text in the textbox during text changed. That was the next time that it fires, the value in that variable is the old value.

Comment: the next time it fires it will overwrite that store old value with the new one though.. for example I store 3 in the variable which is the old value but as soon as the text changes to 4 that variables value changes to 4..

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value of textbox in some variable.
For example
    string currentVal = txtName.Text;

string currentVal can be used as a previous value in text_changed event.

Comment: will never be a previous value though. As soon as the 3 (old value) is changed to a 4 the 3 which was stored will be overwritten.. therefore still cant access the old value else where..

Comment: That depends on where you assign the value of textbox into the variable. You should not assign the value of textbox into the variable in the text changed event.

Comment: What other way have I to store the value?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a timer. Every tick you write the input to a string. If the input of the textbox is not equal to the content in the string, you trigger what you wanted to do. That way you can trigger a void with the old input.

```
private string oldInput;

....

void TimerTick(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (oldInput != MyTextBox.Text) MyVoid(oldInput);
    oldInput = MyTextBox.Text;
}
```